# Export data to XML with sepa-xml-php

Tags: php, xml, composer-php, code-composer, sepa

please I need help I'm trying to create a SEPA XML file so I downloaded the sepa-xml with coenter image description heremposer in my project then I make the same code in the documentation to test if work or not so when I [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ho8p.png)added the code and generate the file I get an empty file. but when I dump the variable I get a result .

[I get this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfYe3.jpg)

Comment: my code is the in the documentation :https://github.com/php-sepa-xml/php-sepa-xml/blob/master/doc/direct_debit.md

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved and your attempts to resolve the problem. How is this problem related to [tag:composer-php] or [tag:code-composer]?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I referred here. Looks like you need to download the generated xml code.
[Git link][1].
Code will be like this.

```
 header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="newfile.xml"');
    header('Content-type: "text/xml"; charset="utf8"');
    echo $directDebit->asXML();
    exit;
```

In this case the generated code will be saved as newfile.xml and download the file automatically. Hope it solves your problem
[1]: https://github.com/php-sepa-xml/php-sepa-xml/blob/master/doc/direct_debit.md